# How to set frequency of render OpenGL ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering, render, renderer

Regular frequency of `onDrawFrame()` method is 16.6 milliseconds (60 fps), but what if I would like to reduce this frequency to 32 milliseconds (30 fps)...

Question is - is there some method like `setFrameFrequency(frequency)`

There is one option that looks applicable `setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)` and call each frame render whenever you want, 30, 25, 60 fps doesn't matter, but this approach looks me a little bit workaround...

Comment: If you simply don't modify the buffer in `GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onDrawFrame()` (e.g., you return immediately), doesn't it leave the previously rendered data on-screen? What I'm saying is, you can choose which frames to render and which to skip; the frame rate is entirely within your control, inasmuch as you can pick & choose which of those 16.6ms frames to render.

Comment: @greeble31 if I understood you correctly you mean that for example if I skip every second frame I will get 30 fps instead of 60? Ok, but how to skip a frames?

Comment: Just don't do anything in `onDrawFrame()`.

Comment: Like, increment a counter each time `onDrawFrame()` is called, and return immediately if `(counter % 2 != 0)`.